# iphone - delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an object that belongs to a class. Lets call it classA. This classA is a subclass of classB.

ClassA has a delegate protocol.

I create an classA object on my main code. This object is inside a view. Lets call it viewX.

Now I am in classB and I would like to get a reference to viewX.

remember that classA has a delegate protocol, so it has a reference to its delegate, that is the viewController where viewX is. From class A I can access viewX doing [delegate view], but how do I do that from classB???

thanks.

Comment: Can you change class B? or is it a class you don't have access to?

Comment: I don't have access to it. Why? does it matter?

Comment: Yea, because if you had access to it, I would say you should add a variable to the class of type id, and set that variable as the view, and that would be a very easy way to do it. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible. But I may be wrong.

Comment: ok. Thanks. If you put that as an answer I will accept it... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to class B, I would say you should add a variable to the class of type id, and set that variable as the view, and that would be a very easy way to do it. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible. But I may be wrong.